# Ramda TypeScript pipe "Expected 0 arguments, but got 1. TS2554" not picking overloads

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

In JavaScript I had a following simple `ramda` function:

```
const isStringOk = (val) => pipe(String, cleanString, (v)=> !!v)(val);
```

When I tried to convert it to type script I got following error:

`Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.  TS2554`

Type overloads were showing in intelisense but somehow compiler was not picking them up.

First I defined function type as:

```
type StingToBoolType = (value: string) => boolean;
```

Next I tried following:

```
const isStringOkPipe : StingToBoolType = pipe<string, string, boolean>(String, cleanString, (v)=> !!v);
const isStringOk = (val: string) => isStringOkPipe(val);
```

So lastly this is final solution:

```
const isStringOk = (val) => (pipe(String, cleanString, (v)=> !!v) as StingToBoolType)(val);
```

So, solution is do the casting : "... **as StingToBoolType**"

I am writing this method as I have not found in previous solution, maybe someone will find it useful.

If you have more condensed way to solve this (pinpoint correct function overload) - please feel free to comment.

Thank you,

Comment: I have no TypeScript suggestions, but it looks as though your function could be written more simply as `const isStringOk = pipe(String, cleanString, Boolean)`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but that function was just an simplified example of real implementation.

Comment: I'm not surprised.  I'm one of the founders of Ramda, but neither I nor any of the core team is particularly versed in TypeScript.  We usually suggest you check these problems with those who maintain your typings files.